# Revoking getUserMedia's ability to capture, and removing the tab warning

Tags: javascript, privacy, getusermedia

I'm working on an Angular SPA. As part of the app, I need to be able to capture an image from the user's webcam/phone camera. I have that working after following [this MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Capture_and_Streams_API/Taking_still_photos).

This issue is though, once `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` runs, the tab that took the image will now permanently have a

> This tab is using your camera or microphone

warning; *even once the user has navigated away from the "page" that took the image* (since this is a SPA, there is only one "page", so navigation just rewrites the current page instead of actually navigating).

---

I understand why the warning is there in the first place, and I understand why it may need to persist for a period (to prevent it from showing for such a short period of time that the user doesn't notice it). Is there a way though to have it *eventually* go away though? I'm worried that the users will be concerned that it's still claiming that we're using their camera, even when we technically aren't.

Given it shows up when `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` is called, I figured there may be a "close" method on the stream or `mediaDevices`, but I can't find any such method.

How can I tell the browser that I'm done recording so it can let the user know that we're no longer recording? This is specific to Chrome, but general solutions would be welcome as well.